# On two kinds of powers of Ideals related to Symbolic powers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, primary-decomposition

All rings below are commutative, with unity and Noetherian.

For a prime ideal $P$ in $R$, if $\phi_P : R \to R_P$ is the localisation map, and $I$ is an ideal in $R_P$, let us write $I \cap R$ to mean $\phi_P^{-1} (I)$.

For an ideal $J$ in $R$ and integer $n\ge 1$ , let us define $J^{\{n\}} := \cap_{P \in Min Ass (R/J)} (J^nR_P \cap R)$ ; where $Min Ass (R/J)$ is just the collection of minimal primes over $J$.

$J^{[n]} := \cap_{J \subseteq P} (J^nR_P \cap R)$  and let $J^{(n)}$ be the usual symbolic power defined as

$J^{(n)} := \cap_{P \in  Ass (R/J)} (J^nR_P \cap R)$.

Obviously we have the chain : $ J^{[n]} \subseteq J^{(n)} \subseteq J^{\{n\}}$ .

Is there any nice conditions on $R$ or $J$ which makes any of the above inclusions an equality ? Also , I would like to know, does the other two powers I have defined, apart from the symbolic power, exist in literature ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you want them to be equal?

Comment: @Youngsu: no not really ... just pure curiosity ...

Comment: Thanks. I do not know any results of the symbolic powers of an ideal even in the case $J^{(n)} \neq J^{\{n \}}$. Do you have any reference?